# Why current opened div doesn't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have one question about jQuery close system. I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/ZWYjmr)** from codepen.io

In this demo you can see there are two div (red and blue). When you click the red div then the `.CRtW11` will be an active. But after you click the blue div the `.CRtW11` stayed on there; it needs to be inactive. What is the problem there, can anyone tell me ?

JS

```
// FOR cR
$("body").on("click", ".cR", function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   var $current = $(this).find('.CRtW11').toggleClass("CRtW11-active");
   $('.CRtW11').not($current).removeClass('CRtW11-active');
   var $currenta = $(this).find('.ReaC').toggleClass("ReaC-active");
   $(".ReaC").not($currenta).removeClass("ReaC-active");
});
$("body").click(function() {
   $(".CRtW11").removeClass("CRtW11-active");
   $(".ReaC").removeClass("ReaC-active");
});

// FOR Br
$("body").on("click",".Br", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $current = $(this).find(".BRc").toggleClass("BRc-active");
   $(".BRc").not($current).removeClass("BRc-active");
});
$("body").on("click", function(){
   $(".BRc").removeClass("BRc-active");
});
```

Comment: There's got to be a bettre way to do this. this code is so messed up... To answer your question : you need to add the line to remove the CRtw11 active  class in your .Br click handler function :  $(".CRtW11").removeClass("CRtW11-active");

Comment: Because you aren't removing the `CRtW11-active` and `ReaC-active` classes in your `Br` click handler.

Comment: I have updated your code and created a fiddle kindly check.. https://jsfiddle.net/wzbenpw8/  is this you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("body").click(function() {
   $(".CRtW11").removeClass("CRtW11-active");
   $(".ReaC").removeClass("ReaC-active");
});
```

This function wont work for the red and blue div as their click events are stopped in their respective click functions. So the simple solution will be to add the remove class function in the opposite click functions. i.e.

```
    // FOR cR
$("body").on("click", ".cR", function(event) {
   $(".BRc").removeClass("BRc-active");
   event.stopPropagation();
   var $current = $(this).find('.CRtW11').toggleClass("CRtW11-active");
   $('.CRtW11').not($current).removeClass('CRtW11-active');
   var $currenta = $(this).find('.ReaC').toggleClass("ReaC-active");
   $(".ReaC").not($currenta).removeClass("ReaC-active");
});
$("body").click(function() {
   $(".CRtW11").removeClass("CRtW11-active");
   $(".ReaC").removeClass("ReaC-active");
});

// FOR Br
$("body").on("click",".Br", function(event) {
    $(".CRtW11").removeClass("CRtW11-active");
   $(".ReaC").removeClass("ReaC-active");
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $current = $(this).find(".BRc").toggleClass("BRc-active");
   $(".BRc").not($current).removeClass("BRc-active");
});
$("body").on("click", function(){
   $(".BRc").removeClass("BRc-active");
});
```